# How can I conduct a post via Javascript from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to conduct a `POST` request via jQuery.

Say I have four Javascript variables: `var1`,`var2`,`var3`,`var4` and a endpoint of URL.

How would I `POST` via jQuery (I would rather not be using Ajax for the sake of this example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put these variables into the form via hidden labels, and submit it.

If you can place a div in the html with id="myDivContent", you could add them there

```
var myStr = '<input name="var1" type="hidden" value="' + var1 + '" />';
myStr += '<input name="var2" type="hidden" value="' + var2 + '" />';
myStr += '<input name="var3" type="hidden" value="' + var3 + '" />';
$('#myDivContent').innerHTML = myStr;
$('form#myForm').submit();
```

If you just want to create a form on the fly, put these vars in there and make a POST request, then I need to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this use-case.

I would rather create a form element(DOM) and set the variables of the form and then submit the form.

This can be done in javascript.

Here is an example.

```
value1 = 1234;
value2 = 5678;
value3 = 9012;
value4 = 3456;

var f = document.createElement("form")
f.method= "post"
f.action = "enpoint.url"
f.innerHTML = f.innerHTML + "<input type='text' name='var1' value='"+value1+"'/>"
f.innerHTML = f.innerHTML + "<input type='text' name='var2' value='"+value2+"'/>"
f.innerHTML = f.innerHTML + "<input type='text' name='var3' value='"+value3+"'/>"
f.innerHTML = f.innerHTML + "<input type='text' name='var4' value='"+value4+"'/>"
f.submit()
```

Comment: that's right. pure javascript should be works like that but the question ask for a jquery POST.

Comment: set id to form and then call jQuery submit.`f.id = 'myform'` and `$("#myform").submit()`

Answer (score 0):

jquery:

```
// var1, var2 ..., my_url must be given

$('input:hidden[name=var1]').val(var1);
$('input:hidden[name=var2]').val(var2);
...
$('#my_form').attr('action', my_url);
$('#my_form').submit();
```

html:

```
<form id="my_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="var1">
    <input type="hidden" name="var2">
        ...
</form>
```

No AJAX. This code actually submit your form as a normal submit action triggered by the user.